# DATE_DIFF BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

DATE_DIFF(CURRENT_DATE('Europe/Paris'), 365, DAY)

Returns me error

No matching signature for function DATE_DIFF for argument types: DATE, INT64, DATE_TIME_PART. Supported signatures: DATE_DIFF(DATE, DATE, DATE_TIME_PART); DATE_DIFF(DATETIME, DATETIME, DATE_TIME_PART); DATE_DIFF(TIMESTAMP, TIMESTAMP, DATE_TIME_PART)

How to correct this ?

My regards,

Answer (score 1):

Use below instead

```
SELECT DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE('Europe/Paris'), INTERVAL 365 DAY)
```

As a shortcut, below also works

```
SELECT CURRENT_DATE('Europe/Paris') - 365
```

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you looking for the function `DATE_SUB`?

```
DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE('Europe/Paris'), INTERVAL 365 DAY)
```

DATE_SUB substracts 365 days from the current date in Paris and returns the corresponding `DATE`.

`DATE_DIFF` in contrast returns the number (therefore an `INT`) of `DATE_TIME_PART` between 2 dates.

See [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions#date_sub) for reference.